# How to escape script tags?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
    // to make tags stable, wrap them into <html> tag
    $post_content_html = "<html>".$html."</html>";

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($post_content_html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//@*');
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if($node->nodeName != "src" && $node->nodeName != "href" && $node->nodeName != "alt") {
            $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
        }
    }

    $post_content_html = $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);

    // To strip <html> tag which been wrapped
    $post_content_html = preg_replace('/^<html>/', '', $post_content_html);
    $post_content_html = preg_replace('/<\/html>$/', '', $post_content_html);
```

As you can see, my code removes `src`, `href` and `alt` attributes. But still, my client is not safe against XSS attacks, since users can inject `<script>` tag as well (including some js codes inside), Any idea how can I escape `script` tag?

Comment: What do you mean by *escape script tag*?

Comment: @NigelRen I want to make it "not working at my website page when the post is published".

Comment: @Alex Is it an option to remove all HTML code? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Although the task of sanitizing HTML seems simple, it's not. You can't reliably *exclude* certain parts of HTML and get something safe. There are a lot (and I mean it) of ways to inject unsafe content, most of which you wouldn't even think of.

The only more or less secure way is to maintain a white-list of HTML tags and attributes and filter attributes content. But since it's a big task, perhaps your best shot would be to use something like http://htmlpurifier.org/

Or even better - do not allow any HTML. Use Markdown, for example, if this is an option at all.